# MySQL : Is there a way to select all rows of a table which have value at specific column in given set of Strings?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

e.g. I have a table Book (id int, author varchar(100)) where id is primary key.
I have a set of authors 'S', How to find all the books such that their author is present in the set.

P.S. I am using java.

Comment: How you are storing author values? are they comma separated?

Comment: There is no other table for authors as such

Comment: I am asking how you are storing authors? is in this format S,A,C ? There are multiple authors for a single book and a single author can have multiple books. Is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for this.

```
    SELECT * FROM book
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('author_name', author)
```

**EDIT**

```
    SELECT * FROM book b
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(b.author, 'Atal,Jawahar,Gandhi,Patel')
```

Comment: is variable author a set here?

Comment: Yes. As you have mentioned "in given set of strings" in the question

Comment: Let us say I want to run this query in mysql console, then how will I make this set? I have been given 4 authors "Atal", "Jawahar", "Gandhi", "Patel".